# How to avoid publishing a feature branch too soon, while keeping it current with development?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Our team has a `master` branch which is the code that's in Production.

We typically have multiple feature branches that are being worked on at a time. Each derived from our `master` branch (production)

The developers push to the `development` branch several times a day (test environment).

In order to stay on top of changes (i.e. resolve conflicts), I find I need to keep the feature branches I'm actively working on up to date with `develop`.

Should we merged from the development branch into our feature branches in order to be on sync with other developers and avoid conflicts?

If a feature branch is not ready for production wouldn't that feature be in the other's developers feature branch?

Comment: This can be answered based on a "specific expertise". In this instance: mine.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you would not need to keep the feature branch "on top of changes" *all* the time.
But any time you need to publish a feature branch to develop (in order to push it to test, testing it in integration), then rebase the feature branch(es) first on top of develop, then (trivial) merge it.

Make sure to [activate `git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) in order to not have to resolve the same merge conflicts over and over again.